# deploy a laravel project still show 404 not found,but php -S 0.0.0.0:port works

Tags: php, laravel, nginx

I'm trying to deploy a project to a `vm(linux-nginx-mysql)`.

It's a opensource project called Flarepoint.

I set the `conf(nginx/sites-enabled/default)` root to `var/www/html/Flarepoint-crm/public`

When I go to the `/{projectName}/public/` or use command `php -S 0.0.0.0:8888` it works and the URL redirects to `domain.com/login`

But  when I visit the URL: `domain.com` it redirects to `domain.com/login` and shows 404 not found.

Can somebody help me?

Comment: Please don't tag web servers that are not relevant. Apache has nothing to do with Nginx .

Comment: sry. it is system recommended

Comment: I'm not a Laravel user but I'd be surprised if it recommends Apache over Nginx since the interaction of most modern PHP frameworks with the web server is minimum. In any case, you want to install in on Nginx anyway, don't you?

Comment: @MaxMMX you should provide the full nginx configuration for the site, its more likely that you miss configure it